# Не могу понять особенностей POST запроса в fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

Пытаюсь отправить POST запрос через `fetch`. Ранее для этих целей использовал jquery `$.ajax`

Вот мой код:

```js
fetch("/", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: 'mode=ajax&action=delete_opt&opt=' + this.arr_opt_to_delete

  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

В принимающем коде, в PHP скрипте, делаю вывод в файл:

```
file_put_contents("/home/web/ing.txt", print_r($_POST, true), FILE_APPEND);
```

И получаю результат:

```
Array
(
    [mode] => ajax
    [action] => delete_opt
    [opt] => ite,koni,vio
)
```

Ранее я использовал jquery `$.ajax` и получал как и положено массив. Добавил код:

```js
$.ajax("/", {
  cache: false,
  data: {
    "mode": "ajax",
    "action": "delete_opt",
    "opt": this.arr_opt_to_delete
  },
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(dt) {

    console.log(dt);

  },
  error: function() {
    alert("err55");
  }
});
```

И ожидаемо получил:

```
Array
(
    [mode] => ajax
    [action] => delete_opt
    [opt] => Array
        (
            [0] => ite
            [1] => koni
            [2] => vio
        )

)
```

Почему через jquery `$.ajax` данные `[opt]` приходят как и положено массивом, а через `fetch` я получаю строку `ite,koni,vio` ?? Как добиться, чтобы `[opt]` приходили массивом через `fetch`?

Comment: а где `fetch` используется? оба примера на jquery. Просто с разным content-type. А, показалось. Просто корректный content-type надо поставить

Comment: `fetch` используется внутри `Vue.js`
Именно поэтому вместо привычной для меня `$.ajax` использую `fetch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница заключается в разных content-type.

Поэтому, нужно либо сделать его одинаковым и передавать значения в одинаковом виде

```
const data = {
  "mode": "ajax",
  "action": "delete_opt",
  "opt": this.arr_opt_to_delete
}

fetch("/", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)    
})
```

, либо правильно организовать параметры для текущего content-type, а именно делать параметр `opt` массивом, например:

```
body: 'mode=ajax&action=delete_opt&' + this.arr_opt_to_delete.map(opt=>`opt[]=${opt}`).join('&')
```

Comment: Спасибо! С "Content-type": "application/json; вчера намучался - крутил и так и сяк, но не работало. Там самописная CMS и ей, чтобы переключиться на контроллер, обрабатывающий AJAX-запросы нужно, чтобы в $_GET или $_POST параметре передавался mode=ajax. Из переданного JSON, параметр mode=ajax она прочитать не могла и постоянно бросала меня на index.php. 

``this.arr_opt_to_delete.map(opt=>`opt[]=${opt}`).join('&')`` - то, что нужно! Простое и элегантное решение! За долгие годы настолько привык копипастить jquery $.ajax, что забыл, что элементы массива передаём как opt[]=vio. Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю что массив оформлен не так как нужно для json

```
{
  "items": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "name1" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "name2" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "name3" }
  ] 
}
```